# How to fire an event only when a button with specific id is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5j3r6w/)**

How can I associate an event to be fired only when an specific button (`id`) is clicked?

For example I have two buttons like:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="origin"> Origin</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="destination"> Destination</button>
```

Now I just want to fire the even `view.on()` only when the `#origin` is clicked:

```
view.on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  console.log(event.mapPoint.latitude);    
});
```

I already tried this:

```
view.on("click","#origin", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  console.log(event.mapPoint.latitude);    
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Just attach a click handler to the button with `id = "origin"` like `$('#origin').on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); console.log(e.mapPoint.latitude); });`

Comment: Thanks for comment but I need to handle the event through `view.on()`

Comment: What is `view`? Provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: It is ArcGIS Javascript library Here is demo https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=intro-popup

Comment: So it encompasses the buttons?

Comment: Can u please let me know why down voted this question?

Comment: To detect a click on an element using event delegation, the element needs to be a child of the the `view` element, which yours aren't, hence you won't be able to use `view.on("click", ...)`

Comment: To get a button within the map, and to make use of `view.on("click", ...)` you must most likely use ArcGIS built-in buttons for that (if they have that)

Comment: Am pretty sure those downvotes came as you haven't provided a [mcve], and an external link to a fiddle doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot more details I suspect you want to check the target of the event something like:

```
view.on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'origin'){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    console.log(event.mapPoint.latitude); 
  }   
});
```

Comment: Then create a **runnable** [mcve] and specify what error is also

Comment: oops I did copy the wrong seed too. Remove the `#origin` in function params...see updated

Comment: let me create fiddle

Comment: @MonaCoder To detect a click on an element using event delegation, the element needs to be a child of the the `view` element, which yours aren't, hence you won't be able to use `view.on("click", ...)`